# Error publishing Temporal table using non default file group in VS 2017 SSDT

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, temporal-tables

I use filegroup called [secondary]. I'm using VS 2017 SSDT latest version. I'm trying to alter a table to make it a temporal. When I try to publish it using DB Compare I get an error.

Severity    Code    Description    Project    File    Line    Suppression State
Error        SQL71567: Filegroup: [secondary] cannot be specified on Table: "TableA_History" when there is the clustered Index: on the table.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to create a history table and its index separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to maintain the main and history tables separately. That wwas the only way.